# If the universe can expand at a speed faster than that of light, why don't we feel the effect?

Tags: cosmology, speed-of-light, universe, space-expansion, faster-than-light

the universe, as I have read, is capable of inflating at a speed faster than that of light! How is that even possible if we don't feel the effect?
or does it affect us?

Comment: (Probably) Related: [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2110/), [that question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76779/), and [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/70056/1353).

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine that the Universe is so big and vast that any change or difference in the fabric of the Universe wouldn't have a serous knock on effect.

Also with being so big, when we look into the sky, we are looking into the past. So for all we know something may have happened but the event hasn't reached us yet because of the time it takes.